# Delete cached page in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to develop an app. I run Apache2 web server. I wrote an index.html file and pointed to `http://localhost`

Unfortunately even when I make changes it points to old page which is I think cached in the browser. How do I remove the page and disable caching for `localhost` domain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+F5, or Command+Shift+R.

Or pressing F5, or Command+R twice.